# how to fix the scoring issue in pong game

Tags: java

I am writing one of my first games in java and i need help on the scoring part of it. The score of each player is supposed to increase each time the ball touches the opposing side. on one side it works perfectly fine but on the other it doesn't work. Also, is it healthy/normal to have as many if statements as much as I do in the code?

P.S. I know my code is very messy but this is the first time I am creating something without a full tutorial explaining everything.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Pong extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

int x = 90;
int y = 90;
int rectytop = 30;
int rectytop2 = 30;
int rectybottom = rectytop + 100; 
int rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
int scoreplayer1 = 0;
int scoreplayer2 = 0;
int xedge2= 448;
int border = 30;
int scoreplayer1a = (int) scoreplayer1;
boolean balldown = true;
boolean ballright = true;
boolean playerborderup = false;
boolean playerborderdown = false;
boolean balltouch1 = false;
boolean balltouch2 = false;
boolean w = false;
boolean s = false;
boolean up = false;
boolean down = false;
boolean goalon1 = false;
boolean goalon2 = false;



private void moveball() {

    if (balldown == true){
        y = y + 2;
    }

    if (y >= getHeight()-border){
        balldown = false;
    }
   if (balldown == false){
        y = y - 2;
    }






   if (ballright == true){
       x = x + 2;
   }
   if (x == getWidth()-border){
       ballright = false;
   }
   if (ballright == false){
       x = x - 2;
   }



   if (y == 0){
       balldown = true;
   }

   if (x == 0){
       ballright = true;
   }



   if (balltouch1 == false){
       if (x == 76){
           if(y < rectybottom && y > rectytop){
               ballright = true;
           }
       }
   }


   if (balltouch2 == false){
       if (x == 390 && y < rectybottom2 && y > rectytop2){
               ballright = false;
       }
   }


}    

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    //drawing ball
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    g.fillRect(48 , rectytop, 30, 100);
    g.fillRect(420, rectytop2, 30, 100);

    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 100));
    g.drawString(Integer.toString(scoreplayer1a), 175, 100);
    g.drawString(Integer.toString(scoreplayer2), 300, 100);
}

public Timer timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (w == true){

           if (rectytop == 0){
            playerborderup = true;
            }
           if (rectytop != 0){
            playerborderup = false;
            }
           if (playerborderup == true){
            rectytop = rectytop + 0;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
            }
           if (playerborderup == false){
            rectytop = rectytop - 5;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
            }
    }

    if (s == true){
                        if (rectytop == 585){
            playerborderdown = true;
        }
        if (rectytop != 585){
            playerborderdown = false;
        }
        if (playerborderdown == true){
            rectytop = rectytop - 0;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderdown == false){
            rectytop = rectytop + 5;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    if (up == true){
        if (rectytop2 == 0){
            playerborderup = true;
        }
        if (rectytop2 != 0){
            playerborderup = false;
        }
        if (playerborderup == true){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 + 0;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderup == false){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 - 5;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    if (down == true){
        if (rectytop2 == 585){
            playerborderdown = true;
        }
        if (rectytop2 != 585){
            playerborderdown = false;
        }
        if (playerborderdown == true){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 - 0;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderdown == false){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 + 5;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
    }

  }

    });

  public void start(){
   timer.start();
   }

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //making the window
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Pong Game");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    Pong game = new Pong();
    Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 30);

    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(502, 502);//1024, 724
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.addKeyListener(game);
    f.add(game);
    f.add(p);
    game.start();


    //game code

    f.add(game);        
    while (true){
        game.repaint();
        game.moveball();   

        game.setscore();
        Thread.sleep(10); 
    }
}

public void setscore(){
    if (x == 0){
        goalon1 = true;
    }

    if (x != 0){
        goalon1 = false;
    }

    if (x == getWidth()-30){
        goalon2 = true;
    }

    if (x != getWidth()-30){
        goalon2 = false;
    }

    if (goalon1 == true){
        scoreplayer2 ++;
    }
    if (goalon2 == true){
        scoreplayer1 = scoreplayer1 + 1;

    }


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    //player one
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
       w = true;     
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
       s = true; 
    }


    //player two
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        up = true;

    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        down = true;
    }







}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        w = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        s = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        up = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        down = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We're not going to read through a literal wall of code to try and GUESS what the problem might be.

Comment: It's normal to have as many if statements as you need. It's definitely not normal to have "if x == 0, goal = true; if x != 0, goal = false". Just say "goal = (x == 0)". (Or if it's more complicated than just setting a single boolean, at least use "else").

Comment: When writing goal=(x==0), does that make it true?

Comment: `is it healthy/normal to have as many if statements as much as I do in the code?` -- Generally not, it makes your code very difficult to read and leads you toward the [arrow anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern)

Comment: The part of the code that I want you people to read is the method setScore()

Comment: What is the value of `x` when you call `setScore()` when it works?  What is the value of `x` when you call `setScore()` when it doesn't work?  Most of the time even 2-3 minutes of debugging into a method makes it clear what is wrong with it.  If you don't know (or have the time to learn) how to use a debugger, you could at least print the value to the console.

Comment: X is the value for the ball's x-axis. I made it so that when ever the ball reaches the edge of the frame, it adds a number to the players score and then prints it out on the paint method

Comment: Spend a little time with a debugger stepping through the code, and/or adding some System.out.println statements to see if your variables are what you think they should be.  Many bugs become obvious once you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a lot of stuff differently for each player for no reason. It would be much more helpful if you narrowed down what part of the code the error was coming from or at least told us which player doesn't work and which does.

I'm not going to read all of the code you posted, but look at differences like this. The error might not be coming from setScore() alone. There is no way to tell without going through everything you posted.

```
if (goalon1 == true){
    scoreplayer2 ++;
}
if (goalon2 == true){
    scoreplayer1 = scoreplayer1 + 1;

}
```

Try to match the code for both players and I'm sure you'll find your mistake

Comment: I did match everything in player 1 and 2. It's player 2 that is not working.

Comment: I have you tried printing out the x value when it hits a wall to make sure it is the screen width - 30?